# How can I update Ruby version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OS X v10.10 (Yosemite)?

Tags: ruby, version

I need to update my Ruby version from 2.0.0 to the latest version. I can not use some gems because my version is not updated.
I had used [Homebrew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homebrew_(package_manager)) to install Ruby some time ago. How can I update my Ruby version?

Comment: what happens when you type `which rvm` or `which rbenv` in your command line

Comment: @ChuchaC Please, take a look [here](https://shellzero.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-update-ruby-2-0-to-the-latest-version-on-mac-os-x-yosemite/) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33883615/1611876)

Comment: looks like `brew install ruby` is enough. [check here](https://flinhong.com/2017/10/26/upgrade-ruby-on-mac/)

Answer (score 923, accepted):

Open your terminal and run

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable
```

For the `rvm` command to work, you need to run:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Now, run `rvm list known`

This shows the list of versions of the Ruby interpreter.

Now, run `rvm install ruby@latest` to get the latest Ruby version.

If you type `ruby -v` in the terminal, you should see `ruby X.X.X`.

If it still shows you `ruby 2.0.`, run `rvm use ruby-X.X.X --default`.

**Prerequisites for Windows 10:**

- C compiler. You can use http://www.mingw.org/
- `make` command available otherwise it will complain that "bash: make: command not found". You can install it by running `mingw-get install msys-make`
- Add "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin" and "C:\MinGW\bin" to your path environment variable

Comment: 2.2.0 is not the latest version of Ruby.

Comment: @Jordan My bad 2.3 is the stable version

Comment: This works on Mac OS to install RVM:
`\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby`

Comment: 2.4 is the latest stable version: rvm install ruby-2.4.0

Comment: RVM (rbenv) seems to be the way to go. You can't upgrade the system ruby  bundled with MacOS.

Comment: I get Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.12/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p551.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.........
Installing required packages: gcc49.. and stuck here forever

Comment: If you get requirements installation failed with status 1 run this code then do the above steps then it works: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

Comment: @chpopov, that's not quite true. For a brew only solution to update ruby see my [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42286604/2628257)

Comment: ruby 2.4.1 doesn't compile when upgrading

Comment: This isn't quite a good solution, because if you want to upgrade ruby version in future, you should do that through rvm. Clearer solution is to install and lead ruby latest version through the brew. Managing 1 tool is easier than 2. Answer below can help on that.

Comment: After updating using the 'rvm install ruby-2.4.2' command, when I type 'ruby -v' - I see I am running the current version (I don't think I need to do the other steps of setting the default anymore)

Comment: I need to update Ruby because Brew asks me to. However, ruby uses brew, so I get:  Homebrew must be run under Ruby 2.3! You're running 2.0.0.... Any solution ?

Comment: to make it work at fish shell, add additional command: `curl -L --create-dirs -o ~/.config/fish/functions/rvm.fish https://raw.github.com/lunks/fish-nuggets/master/functions/rvm.fish`

Comment: piping curl output straight to execution is a security nightmare waiting to happen.

Comment: @zed You should turn that into an answer. That worked for me.

Comment: You are encouraging people to run a cURL'd script. (piping curl output) Do you think that's smart?

Comment: what is the first slash in front of \curl for ?

Comment: The current stable version is 2.5.1

Comment: Wanted to add that `source /Users/[your username]/.rvm/scripts/rvm` in all open terminals should also allow rvm to work!

Comment: It have to be between "" like this $rvm install "ruby-2.4.6"

Comment: As a first step install GPG keys used to verify installation package:


`gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB`

Comment: I got this message: ```RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work```.

Comment: Why this kind of answer keep poping as "Correct"? 1) Piping some online script directly to bash? Are you insane? 2) There are other far more easier and safe solutions (brew, for instance).

Comment: I had to add ` --auto-dotfiles` as suggested by the instructions, and run with `sudo`.

Comment: After the installation you don't need to restart Terminal to start using `rvm`.
You should only need to execute the  indicated `source` command, which should work with: `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`.

Comment: pay attention that this line contains two commands that two of them probably requires super user permission
hence, you might want to write this line as follows (mind there are two `sudo` in the line:
`sudo curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | sudo bash -s stable`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work `ruby --version
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.arm64e-darwin21]
`

Comment: The gpg fix suggested in the comments also fails with this error: `gpg: keyserver receive failed: Network is unreachable`

Answer (score 307):

### Homebrew-only solution

#### A better solution

From the comments (kudos to Maksim Luzik), what seems like a more elegant solution:

> After installing Ruby through brew, run the following command to update the links to the latest Ruby installation: `brew link --overwrite ruby --force`

Reopen a terminal to reset zshrc.
Check the installlation with `ruby --version` and `gem --version`, then run `gem install bundler`.

#### Earlier solution

Using brew is enough. It's not necessary to install rvm and for me it just complicated things.

By `brew install ruby` you're actually installing the latest (currently v2.4.0). However, your path finds 2.0.0 first. To avoid this just change precedence ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8731098/2628257)). I did this by changing `~/.profile` and setting:

`export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH`

After this, I found that the bundler gem was still using version 2.0.0. Just install it again: `gem install bundler`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks. If I was a ruby dev then rvm would make sense, but I'm not, so this is perfect.

Comment: this works, needed to do "source ~/.bash_profile" after install

Comment: or after installing ruby through brew, run following command to update the links to the latest ruby installation: `brew link --overwrite ruby`

Comment: instead of `overwrite` ruby version, you can just write `brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby`

Comment: Late to the party but definitely one of the better guests - worked flawlessly.

Comment: `Error: Could not symlink include/ruby-2.5.0`

Comment: @MaksimLuzik 's solution does not work for me in MacOS. `brew link --overwrite ruby` leads to `Warning: Refusing to link macOS-provided software: ruby`

Comment: Not sure what is is about @rafael-beckel, but just guessing here. How is brew installed? Might be related to sudo rights?

Comment: Thanks for the answer regarding i just need one version of ruby.

Comment: this command to add to PATH worked for me (which is also suggested by brew):

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: If your mac refuses to link ruby, try `brew link --overwrite ruby --force`. This worked for me.

Comment: this worked for me! With `--force`

Comment: Perfect. Perfect. Perfect. My spidey senses told me there was an answer like this out there. Thanks!

Answer (score 132):

I recommend **rbenv*** https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

* If this meets your criteria: [https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv?](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/wiki/Why-rbenv%3F):

> #### rbenv *does…*
>
> - Provide support for specifying **application-specific Ruby versions**.
> - Let you **change the global Ruby version** on a per-user basis.
> - Allow you to **override the Ruby version** with an environment   variable.
>
> #### In contrast with RVM, rbenv *does not…*
>
> - **Need to be loaded into your shell.** Instead, rbenv's shim approach works by adding a directory to your `$PATH`.
> - **Override shell commands like `cd` or require prompt hacks.** That's dangerous and error-prone.
> - **Have a configuration file.** There's nothing to configure except which version of Ruby you want to use.
> - **Install Ruby.** You can build and install Ruby yourself, or use [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) to automate
>   the process.
> - **Manage gemsets.** [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) is a better way to manage application dependencies. If you have projects that are
>   not yet using Bundler you can install the
>   [rbenv-gemset](https://github.com/jf/rbenv-gemset) plugin.
> - **Require changes to Ruby libraries for compatibility.** The simplicity of rbenv means as long as it's in your `$PATH`,
>   [nothing](https://rvm.io/integration/bundler/)
>   [else](https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano/) needs to know about it.

---

#### Installation

Install **Homebrew** http://brew.sh

Then:

```
brew update
brew install rbenv ruby-build

# Add rbenv to Bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile

rbenv install --list
```

Output:

```
Available versions:
 1.8.5-p113
 1.8.5-p114
 […]
 2.3.1
 2.4.0-dev
 jruby-1.5.6
 […]
```

And:

```
rbenv install 2.3.1
```

Set the global version:

```
rbenv global 2.3.1
ruby -v
```

Output:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

If you are not showing the updated version then

```
rbenv rehash
```

Set the local version of your repository by adding `.ruby-version` to your repository's root directory:

```
cd ~/whatevs/projects/new_repo
echo "2.3.1" > .ruby-version
```

For OS X, visit [this link](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra).

Comment: @ChuchaC No prob. But before you do, this is from the rbenv readme: _"Compatibility note: rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv." — https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#installation_

Comment: didn't helped. Still getting standard 2.0.0 version for `ruby -v` after `rbenv global ...`

Comment: There's one additional step after `brew install rbenv`
Run `rbenv init` and add one line to .bash_profile as it states. After that reopen your terminal window, do `rbenv install 2.3.1`, `rbenv global 2.3.1`  and rbenv will do its work

Comment: @SGI I included your additional step in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Probably late but for future references for people who encountered the same issue as @tuxSlayer , `rbenv rehash` after `rbenv global` worked for me

Comment: After `rbenv init`, `ruby -v` outputs the correct version 2.1.2, but bundle runs encounters some error like this `paperclip-5.0.0.beta1 requires ruby version >= 2.1.0, which is incompatible with the current version, ruby 2.0.0p648`. Finally manage to get it work with a run of `rbenv rehash`. Thanks @Sean

Comment: ruby 2.4.1 doesn't compile when upgrading

Comment: I also had to close and re-open Terminal after the suggestions above to get `ruby -v` to show the correct version

Answer (score 74):

Open Terminal:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

It works!

Comment: This does indeed seem to work, and is a unmeasurably more straight forward than the other answers. But when installing some gems (listen for example) they complain that the version is lower than required.

Comment: This is gem not ruby

Comment: Brew only solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42286604/2628257)

Comment: I was misled by this answer too.  It "works" in that no errors are generated when you run it from the console.  However, it does not update Ruby.  It updates Ruby Gems.  Follow one of the other answers to update Ruby (using OS X Sierra).

Comment: Tried it, but i got the following error: ```ERROR:  Error installing rubygems-update:
        rubygems-update requires Ruby version >= 2.3.0.
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `version' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 65):

A **fast** way to upgrade Ruby to **v2.4+**

```
brew upgrade ruby
```

or

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Comment: This appears to do a ton of stuff, but upgrading ruby isn't one of them. It terminates with:

`/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:12:in '<main>': Homebrew must be run under Ruby 2.3! You're running 2.0.0. (RuntimeError)`

Comment: This is the correct and best way to upgrade ruby version using brew.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/gem`

Comment: @SébastienLoisel can you please give some detail about your OS, command etc.

Comment: @fatihyildizhan apparently ruby/gems/etc is in a semibroken state on Mavericks. I've resolved my issues by upgrading to Catalina. I don't remember all the errors I had, but there were multitudes. I can't remember if I was trying to upgrade cocoapods or gems or what, but it was essentially hopeless.

Comment: Mavericks = [Mac OS X v10.9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_X_Mavericks) (2013). Catalina = [macOS v10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (2019). Mac OS X v10.10 (the one in the question) is from 2014. (It may not be relevant, but Catalina introduced [Z Shell as the default shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina#Removed_or_changed_components) (instead of Bash))

Answer (score 48):

You can specify the latest version of Ruby by looking at *[Download Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/)*.

1. Fetch the latest version:

   ```
   curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
   ```
2. Install it:

   ```
   rvm install 2.2
   ```
3. Use it as default:

   ```
   rvm use 2.2 --default
   ```

Or run the latest command from ruby:

```
rvm install ruby --latest
rvm use 2.2 --default
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Solution with `rbenv` wasn't working

Comment: This worked for me too!! The solution with `rbenv` did NOT work

Comment: On Mac I had to do `source ~/.bash_profile` to use `rvm`

Answer (score 14):

##### ✅ Working 2023 method:

Upgrade using Homebrew:

```
brew upgrade ruby
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
brew link --overwrite ruby
```

Then **restart the Terminal** (make sure you terminate all instances, quit and open again)

Then `ruby -v` to check if it linked correctly.

---

#### Recommended Followup:

It's not required, but you can run the following after upgrading Ruby to update gem files:

```
gem update --system 3.4.2
```

<sub>⚠️ The above version may be changed when you have upgraded your Ruby installation. Please use the correct version as reported after the installation of Ruby.</sub>

Comment: this assumes zshell, which while the default shell on newer macs, many still use bash.

Answer (score 11):

Use:

`brew install rbenv ruby-build`

Add *rbenv* to Bash so that it loads every time you open a terminal:

`echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile`

`source ~/.bash_profile`

##### Install Ruby

`rbenv install 2.6.5`

`rbenv global 2.6.5`

`ruby -v`

Link to the [source page](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra#ruby).

Comment: This "rbenv" may refer to [SoAwesomeMan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-can-i-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-os-x-v10-10-yo/38194231#38194231).

Answer (score 3):

In case of the error **“Requirements installation failed with status: 1.”**, here's what to do:

Install Homebrew (for some reason it might not work automatically) with this command:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then proceed to install rvm again using

```
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

Quit, reopen Terminal, and then:

```
rvm install 2.2
rvm use 2.2 --default
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the steps below due to [React Native](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)#React_Native) 0.70 and [macOS v12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey) (Monterey).

```
brew install ruby
```

Edit *.zshrc*:

```
open -e ~/.zshrc
```

Set the $PATH environment variable. Add this at the end of your ~/.zshrc file. On Mac Intel:

```bash
if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
  eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi
```

##### [Apple silicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_silicon)

```bash
if [ -d "/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
      export PATH=/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
      export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
      eval "$(rbenv init -)"
    fi
```

Don't want Homebrew to update your version? Then:

```
brew pin ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal: `rvm gemset use global`

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sudo gem update --system
```

And simply restart the PC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the steps mentioned in *[How to install Ruby in a macOS for local development](https://snyk.io/blog/how-to-install-ruby-in-mac-os/)*.

It worked great for me on [macOS v13.3.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) (a) (22E772610a).

Comment: What is "22E772610a"? Some kind of version number (building number)? A Mac model number? Something else?

Comment: @PeterMortensen it is the build number for macOS v13.3.1 (a)

Answer (score -2):

```
brew link --overwrite --force ruby
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old, well answered question, please explain how it complements *all* other answers.

Answer (score -3):

The simplest way is definitely to enter the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

You can add the flag `--no-document` if you do not want to download the documentation. Here is sample output after running the command:

```
sudo gem update --system
Password:
Updating rubygems-update
Fetching: rubygems-update-2.6.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.6.8
Parsing documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.8
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.8
Installing darkfish documentation for rubygems-update-2.6.8
Installing RubyGems 2.6.8
RubyGems 2.6.8 installed
Parsing documentation for rubygems-2.6.8
Installing ri documentation for rubygems-2.6.8

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/gem

Ruby Interactive (ri) documentation was installed. ri is kind of like man
pages for ruby libraries. You may access it like this:
  ri Classname
  ri Classname.class_method
  ri Classname#instance_method
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40425616/2254698)?  I'm curious why the number of downvotes here versus upvotes there?  Is it because of the duplicate answer, or is it because people did not realize soon enough, that the earlier solution was also just for rubygems, not Ruby?