# "pod init" giving error "-bash: pod: command not found"

Tags: xcode, cocoa, terminal, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to create a Podfile for my Xcode project for Firebase compatibility, but when I try to create it within the same file that my Xcode project is stored in, using my terminal and typing "pod init", it throws the error "-bash: pod: command not found".

I am up to date on OSX as far as I'm aware, using Sierra 10.12.1, but I am unfamiliar with the use of Podfiles, so any help here would be great, thanks.

Comment: Did you install the cocoapods gem?

Comment: No I didn't, I actually didn't realise it had to be installed manually, it's working now though after installation, thanks.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Looks like you didn't install CocoaPods.

To do that you install it through ruby gems, like this:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If you don't have admin privileges, try:

```
gem install cocoapods --user-install
```

Answer (score 21):

if the 1st command doesn't work, try the 2nd command

```
sudo gem install cocoapods

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

In my case, the 2nd command worked

Answer (score 11):

For OS Catalina (**as of December 2019**)

```
gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 8):

### Brew install

```
$ brew install cocoapods
```

For me `sudo gem install cocoapods`did not work.
When I tried `$sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods` it threw me weird error messages. But `brew install` was pretty neat.

Comment: Tried this. But was getting error, Could not find CFProprtyList. So tried sudo gem install cocoapods and it worked. Not sure what happened though. If someone could explain, that would be great!

Comment: Brew worked. Even when Cocoapods installed via the traditional method, I couldn't pod init as pod wasn't found. Not sure if it helps but I'm running on Big Sur.

Answer (score 2):

Got this error today. Was able to resolve it by making sure I had `ruby` in my `PATH`.

```
export PATH=/usr/bin/ruby:$PATH
```

Then (as suggested by [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41065160/1609802) above) run

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Or

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem yesterday, I reckon others in my situation will be too. So I am running a mac OS siera on a virtual machine on my windows so I can use xcode. Firstly you will need to update your version of ruby, it has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38194139/7451779.

Once updated this just run: $ sudo gem install cocoapods

After all this $ pod init should work