# Generating a controller in rails raises TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error:

```
$ rails generate controller orders
DEPRECATION WARNING:
Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.
Please upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 or greater as soon as possible.

/home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:254:in `merge': can't convert String into Hash (TypeError)
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:254:in `root'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1321:in `root'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/config/routes.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `instance_exec'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:289:in `eval_block'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/actionpack-3.2.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:267:in `draw'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `block in load'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `call'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:78:in `execute'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute_if_updated'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:66:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
        from /home2/shsprogr/rails/frothyfox/vendor/cache/ruby/1.9.3/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 with Ruby 1.9.3 and I haven't done anything to it except `rails new frothyfox` and `bundle install`. I'm unsure as to why it's doing this, and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Update your ruby version greater than 1.9.3

Comment: The error Message seems to tell you what the issue is. `Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.
Please upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 or greater as soon as possible.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sass 3.5 will no longer support Ruby 1.9.3.
Please upgrade to Ruby 2.0.0 or greater as soon as possible.
```

This error tells you exactly what you need to do. Your using Ruby 1.9.3; you're also using SASS 3.5 which no longer supports that version of ruby. Simply update your Ruby version to the latest one.

If you need help with that check out these steps [How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite)

Comment: Different version, same steps