# how to update ruby version in mac osx yosemite 10.10?

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I'm trying to update ruby in mac yosemite because I wan't install jekyll but I can't do it. I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite) and I followed the steps mentioned in the best answer but it doesn't work, when I run `rvm install ruby-2.4.1` I take this error:

`Requirements installation failed with status: 2.`

osx: Yosemite 10.10.5
rvm: rvm 1.29.3
ruby: 2.0.0p481

p.s. I also tried the solution mentioned in that topic but it didn't work either and I can't reply (no enough reputation points)

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the gatekeeper
run in terminal:

sudo spctl --master-disable

aunch System Preferences and go to “Security & Privacy” and the “General” tab
You will now see the “Anywhere” option under ‘Allow apps downloaded from:’ Gatekeeper options. Enable it and try again

Comment: thanks for answer, "anywhere" option is already selected, but it doesn't work. When I run `rvm install ruby-2.4.1` I get this error: Requirements installation failed with status: 1. , and when I run `rvm install ruby-2.4.1` as sudo I get: Requirements installation failed with status: 2.

Comment: and the  root user is also enabled? You first have to run the Directory Utility.
Then go to the Edit menu and select "Enable Root User".
You will be asked for the root password twice.
You are done!

Comment: done but, should I log in as root and repeat all steps? In what directory?

Comment: yes, you can simply type root at the login prompt and enter the root password. try the same directory

Comment: ok last thing is to disable the sip. boot while holding cmd +r and run terminal csrutil disable; reboot          and try again, now sip is diabled  you can simple reboot to enable again

Comment: I was wrong, I should had installed homebrew before. Now I can install most recent version of ruby. sorry and thanks for answer : )