# Non-portable path to file yoga-prefix.pch, specified path differs in case. Corrupted file path with duplicated characters

Tags: xcode, react-native, cocoapods, xcode9.2

I've created a project with **react-native-cli** and installed some pods via **cocoapods** but eveytime I try building the project in Xcode it gives me this strange error:

**Non-portable path to file /UUsersCcrysilDDesktopaapp-demoiiosPPodsTTarget Support Filesyyogayyoga-prefix.pch; specified path differs in case from the file name on disk**

For some reason the path duplicates the first character for each file/folder and removes all backslashes. I can find this file without problems in the finder and I haven't touched any of the path variables automatically set by cocoapods so I'm not sure what could be causing this. 
I've also tried deleting all the pods and reinstalling them, deleting the whole /ios folder and rebuilding it but nothing seems to work.

I'm using Xcode 9.2, react-native 0.53.3 and cocoapods 1.4.0 and here's my Podfile incase it might help: 
https://nofile.io/f/6oCNuZ6HEYb/Podfile

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 15):

For me, I had to remove and reinstall *both* `node_modules` and `Pods`. Always reinstall `node_modules` first, as Pods rely on them.

```
rm -Rf node_nodules
npm install
cd ios
rm -Rf Pods
pod install
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the only working solution was to remove the pods

`rm -Rf Pods`
`pod install`
rebuild

Answer (score 1):

[image]

For me, changing 'yoga' to 'Yoga' in the path for Prefix Header got rid of the error

Answer (score 0):

Remove the node_modules
Add the dependencies back using yarn or npm install
This should remove this error

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fix this problem:

- install rvm ([How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite))
- install the latest ruby via rvm. Run the following command to see the latest version of ruby: `run rvm list known`
- At the time of this solution, the ruby was ruby-2.4.1 so I run: `rvm install ruby-2.4.1`
- Go to Ling iOS folder. Run:

  1. `gem update --system`
  2. `gem install cocoapods`
  3. `pod install`