# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod

Tags: ionic-framework, node-modules, ionic-native

Platform: Ionic 
Trying to install a plugin, no pluging getting installed. 
Following error appears:

```
ionic cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin
> cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin --save
Installing "onesignal-cordova-plugin" for ios

Failed to install 'onesignal-cordova-plugin': Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/Users/heptagon/infos/platforms/ios/cordova/version'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.chmodSync (fs.js:1154:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:176:24
    at Array.map (native)
    at callEngineScripts (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:169:17)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/plugman/install.js:311:16
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/q/q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44

(node:1127) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, chmod '/Users/{my username is here }/infos/platforms/ios/cordova/version'
```

Comment: Try to delete this directory `/usr/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/onesignal-cordova-plugin` and then try to reinstall the plugin

Comment: Fixed the problem with updating ruby version,it took me weeks to realise this, found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite

Comment: I had the same error and was able to fix it by uninstalling phonegap.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem with updating ruby version,it took me weeks to realise this, found the solution here: 
[How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite)