# Installing Cocoapods Error

Tags: swift, installation, cocoapods

When I try to install cocoapods I get this error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cocoapods' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect 
returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: tlsv1 alert 
protocol version (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

I thought I had already downloaded cocoapods but when I check for the version using

```
pods --version
```

I get this:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in `to_specs': Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among 30 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:307:in`to_spec'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in`'

Any ideas on how to fix it? Thanks in advance and sorry for the formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out! Just had to update Ruby and it worked. Credit to this post: [How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite)