# Ruby -v shows 2.6.3, but Terminal says I'm running 2.3.7 when trying to run rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just updated ruby, and running `ruby -v` in terminal shows: `ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [x86_64-darwin18]`

However, when trying to run `rails console`, I get the error:

```
Rails 6 requires Ruby 2.5.0 or newer.

You're running
  ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]

Please upgrade to Ruby 2.5.0 or newer to continue.
```

Which is the version I just (allegedly) updated from. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does `which rails` show?

Comment: Also, how exactly did you update Ruby? If you are accessing Ruby through shims or bash functions, your terminal might be stale or you might be in a similar in-between state.

Comment: `which rails` shows usr/bin/rails

Answer (score 1):

Because in your local development, you had some `ruby` versions which was installed, and it set `ruby 2.3.7` as default.

If you installed `ruby` via `rvm`, you can check and list all `ruby` versions in your local via command:

`rvm list`

For examples:

```
   ruby-2.6.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.6.2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.6.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

As you see, you can use this command as bellow to set default `ruby` to use.

`rvm use 2.6.3 --default`

Comment: rvm list showed `# Default ruby not set. Try 'rvm alias create default <ruby>'.`

I tried your suggestion, and got some errors: `Warning! Executable 'ruby' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!`
`Warning! Executable 'gem' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!
`Warning! Executable 'irb' missing, something went wrong with this ruby installation!`

Answer (score 0):

I had to run `rvm implode` , then re-install rvm. Then I followed the instructions found here: [How to update Ruby Version 2.0.0 to the latest version in Mac OSX Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38194032/how-to-update-ruby-version-2-0-0-to-the-latest-version-in-mac-osx-yosemite)

Thank you!