# RVM showing Ruby version in ZSH

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I just installed rvm to upgrade ruby using the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33883615/can-i-upgrade-to-the-current-version-of-ruby-2-2-3-on-os-x-v10-6-8). After installation my zsh instance now always displays rvm:ruby-2.3.0, as per this image:

[image]

I'd rather it not appear but I'm having trouble finding where it's set, any thoughts? It's pretty annoying.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Your prompt is set in a `.zsh-theme` file that is specified in your
>   `.zshrc` file in your home directory.

**Changing to another theme:**

If you want to change your prompt to a preexisting one, open your `.zshrc` file with your favorite text editor. Your can find your `.zshrc` in `~/.zshrc`. When you open that file you will see a line that looks something like this: `ZSH_THEME="gallois"`. (It looks like you're using gallois)

This is the line that you should change if you want to change your entire prompt. For example, change your this from `ZSH_THEME="gallois"` to `ZSH_THEME="dallas"` to change to the preexisting dallas theme. Click [here](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes) For a list of all the default themes and what they look like. These themes are located in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes`.

You should then run `. ~/.zshrc` to source zsh and you will see the new prompt.

**Editing the gallois theme to remove the right prompt**

These themes are located in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes`. I would recommend copying the `gallois.zsh-theme` file and making some other file like `yourname.zsh-theme`. In the theme file you can remove the right prompt entirely by removing the line below this comment:

```
# Combine it all into a final right-side prompt
RPS1='$(git_custom_status)$(ruby_prompt_info) $EPS1'
```

You should probably remove this from the theme file as well for good measure:

```
# RVM component of prompt
ZSH_THEME_RVM_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[red]%}["
ZSH_THEME_RVM_PROMPT_SUFFIX="]%{$reset_color%}"

#Customized git status, oh-my-zsh currently does not allow render dirty status before branch
git_custom_status() {
  local cb=$(git_current_branch)
  if [ -n "$cb" ]; then
    echo "$(parse_git_dirty)%{$fg_bold[yellow]%}$(work_in_progress)%{$reset_color%}$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_PREFIX$(git_current_branch)$ZSH_THEME_GIT_PROMPT_SUFFIX"
  fi
}
```

Keep in mind, this will also remove any descriptions about git repos from your prompt. You should then run `. ~/.zshrc` to source zsh and you will see the new prompt.

**Editing the gallois theme to only remove the ruby prompt**

These themes are located in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes`. I would recommend copying the `gallois.zsh-theme` file and making some other file like `yourname.zsh-theme`. In the theme file you can remove just the rvm prompt by removing a portion of this line:

```
# Combine it all into a final right-side prompt
RPS1='$(git_custom_status)$(ruby_prompt_info) $EPS1'
```

If you just remove the `$(ruby_prompt_info)` portion so that it looks like this:

```
# Combine it all into a final right-side prompt
RPS1='$(git_custom_status) $EPS1'
```

Then you can skip to the end and only remove the rvm portion of the prompt. I would also recommend removing these lines to avoid cluttering the theme file:

```
# RVM component of prompt
ZSH_THEME_RVM_PROMPT_PREFIX="%{$fg[red]%}["
ZSH_THEME_RVM_PROMPT_SUFFIX="]%{$reset_color%}"
```

You should then run `. ~/.zshrc` to source zsh and you will see the new prompt.

Comment: if, like me, you were going nuts making changes to your theme file that were not reflected in the actual shell, check to see if your theme is being loaded from a `custom` folder instead of the `themes` folder.

Answer (score 14):

If, like me, you ended up here because of this problem with the `powerlevel10k` theme, do the following to disable the `rvm` [segment](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k#batteries-included):

1. Open `~/.p10k.zsh`
2. Find the line:

   ```
   rvm                     # ruby version from rvm (https://rvm.io)
   ```
3. Comment it out:

   ```
   # rvm                     # ruby version from rvm (https://rvm.io)
   ```
4. Open a new terminal

Comment: my codespaces in github all of a sudden were showing the ruby version, so thanks for the pro tip here to comment this line out.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to hide the ruby version information is to override the `ruby_prompt_info()` function used to determine what gets included in the prompt.

To do this, edit your `~/.zshrc` and add the following *after* `$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm` has been sourced:

```sh
# hide ruby version from ps1
function ruby_prompt_info() { echo '' }
```